# Probability of top card being a diamond when its known that 2nd card in deck is 8

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am given a deck of 52 card which is randomly well shuffled . I am told beforehand that 2nd card is a '8' , then what would be probability that first card is diamond ? 
I think that since I know that 2nd card is a '8' , it reduces probability of diamond being in first place as '8' could  be of any four set but I can't figure out how much exactly it would reduce probability , are these events independent? I think they might not be independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second card is 8D then the probability the first is a D is 12/51, If the second card is one of 8S,8C,8H then the probability that the first is a D is 13/51. These two cases, given one of them does occur, occur with probabilities 1/4 and 3/4 respectively. So the probability that the first card is a D given the second is an 8 is:
$$
p=\frac{12}{51}\times\frac{1}{4}+\frac{13}{51}\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Which is also obvious from any one of a number of symmetry arguments. If you can't see a symmetry argument in its favour it is also obtainable from the appropriate contingency tree analysis (which the above essentially is but without the diagram)

Comment: Awesome , it would have been hard to get myself convinced without mathematics saying so

Answer (score 1):

Why would the second card being 8 change the chance of the first card being a diamond?  The density of diamonds is the same among the 8s and the non-8s.

Comment: What is meant by density here and how it is same among the 8s and the non-8s.?